# Moodle & vBulletin bridge

Tags: authentication, moodle, vbulletin, bridge

Are there any plugins or easy ready-to-use solutions which can create a "login bridge" between vBulletin and Moodle 2.5? I've seen the LDAP plugin for Moodle only works through 2.4.

Open to all advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [vBSSO for Moodle](http://vbsso.com/platforms/moodle/), working for Moodle 2.x versions.

Comment: I'm looking into this, thank you, but have encountered difficulties with installing it on 2.5. It doesn't let me use the "plugin" installer...even after I pull the "upload" folder out of the zip, re-zip it, and use that. When using that method, it can't find version.php. When using the method they outline on the page, Moodle doesn't see the plugins for me to activate it. What am I doing wrong? I've also submitted a ticket with vbsso, and if I get an answer, I'll post it here.